# How can I fetch EXPLAIN PLAN FOR an Oracle SQL query from PHP?

Tags: php, oracle, sql-execution-plan

I'm using Oracle 10g Express on Windows XP, and on a Macbook OS X 10.5.8 running PHP 5.3.1 with PDO and Oracle Instant Client 10.2.0.4.0_4, I run the following script:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("oci:dbname=winders:1521/xe", "system", "XXXXXX");
...

$sql = "WITH NumberedBugs AS (
    SELECT b.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bug_id) AS RN 
    FROM Bugs b
) SELECT * FROM NumberedBugs WHERE RN = :offset";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($offset);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

No problem.  But I also want to be able to write a PHP script that gets the `EXPLAIN PLAN` report for this query.  When I try this, I get an error:

```
$sql = "EXPLAIN PLAN FOR WITH NumberedBugs AS (
    SELECT b.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bug_id) AS RN 
    FROM Bugs b
) SELECT * FROM NumberedBugs WHERE RN = 1234";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

(I changed the query parameter to a hard-coded integer literal for this test.)

I get this error when I try to call `fetch()`:

> ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch

What's the explanation of this, and how can I get the `EXPLAIN PLAN` report from a PHP script?  I've done some web searches for this error, but I couldn't find a clear enough explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EXPLAIN PLAN FOR` only writes the execution plan into a table (default [`plan_table`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_2431.htm)).

To actually read the explain plan you could do a plain select from this table, or do a

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);
```

after your first query to get a formatted output.

See [Using EXPLAIN PLAN](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm) for more information.

Comment: Do you mean I would `execute()` the first query but fetch no results, and then run a new query against `plan_table`?  Or do I just need to `prepare()` the first query but not execute it?

Comment: Aha, I tried it.  It seems I need to prepare and execute the first query, but I don't fetch any results.  Then run the new query against either `plan_table` or `TABLE(dbms_xplan.display)`.  They give results in different formats.

Comment: Yes, correct. `plan_table` contains all the information provided by `EXPLAIN PLAN`. `dbms_xplan.display` uses the data of the last query you explained and displays it in a format that's easier to read.